# How to Change Save Location in Office 2013 using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, office365

I am wondering how to change the save location in Office 2013 by using VBScript.

Can any one help with that?

Thanks

Comment: See [Using Scripts to Manage Word's File Locations Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692780.aspx), two seconds on google found this.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro changing the document paths (Alt + T, O, File Locations tab). The relevant code recorded is

```
Options.DefaultFilePath(Path:=wdDocumentsPath) = _
    "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
```

In VBS, which doesn't support named arguments (and `options` isn't in the global namespace as app objects are when hosted by that app), becomes

```
wrd.Options.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\"
```

To open word with  `wrd` set as the app object use  `set wrd = createobject("Word.Application")`.

Comment: Can't you just use `wrd.options.DefaultFilepath(0) = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"`? See [WdDefaultFilePath Enumeration (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839487.aspx) and also [Using Scripts to Manage Word's File Locations Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692780.aspx)

Comment: does that work for any of the Office 365 location or just one?